# Matlab Spectrogram Function - cannot find dB values in data

Tags: matlab

I am currently running a Matlab program that reads a few audio files and displays their power spectrograms.

I am trying to find the dB/Freq value at a given time and frequency. Right now, I can look at the graph and can see x,y,z values that make sense to me (x is frequency, y is time, and z is the dB/Hz:
[image: spectrogram]

In my code, I am trying to find that specific dB/Hz value as I iterate through the time and frequencies. I am having a bit of trouble understanding the spectrogram function, though. When I use the line below, what is P suppose to look like? Since my Power/Frequency scale is from -80 to -100, I am confused why when I display P, it is a matrix full of decimal values that are all very similar (around 0.0000 to 0.0002). I am confused what this represents? And how I can find the matrix containing values around the scale I see in the picture?

[S, F, T, P, Fc, Tc] = spectrogram(...);

Currently what I have is:

````
```
clicky = audioread('ChamberTesting_Feb13.wav'); %normalized

quiet_n = audioread('quiet60_normalized.wav'); %normalized

%spectrogram(clicky(:,1),1000,500,1000,Fs); %channel 1 spectrogram
spectrogram(quiet_n(:,1),1000,500,1000,Fs); %channel 1 spectrogram
view(90,90)

%s = spectrogram(clicky(:,1),1000,500,1000,Fs);
s = spectrogram(quiet_n(:,1),1000,500,1000,Fs);
C = get(gca, 'children');
X = get(C, 'Xdata');
Y = get(C, 'Ydata');
Z = get(C, 'Zdata');



delta = 1; %change in time from peak
diff = 10;
differences_count = 0;

for j = 1:5
    for i = 1:40
        num_init = Z(i,j)
        num_comp = Z(i, j+delta) 
        if abs(num_init-num_comp)>diff & differences_count<10
            differences_count = differences_count+1;
        end
    end
end

if(differences_count>5)
    disp("CLICKY!")
end```
````

Comment: Can you please provide more information? What are you plotting in this figure? And also generally what are you expecting? the PSD or the Power spectrum? There is a `spectrumtype` input argument for the function where you can choose. The default is PSD.

Comment: @TinoD I am plotting the power spectrum of a .wav file. I am trying to look for a clicking pattern (not necessarily at one frequency), so I thought I could use the power spectrum to see a trend where the power gets very high for a quick moment (the click). I made more progress on it, but now I have the issue of getting the corresponding frequency at a specific dB reading. Updated my original post with what I currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just leave this as a possible answer for now, let me know if it works for your scaling:

```
[S, F, T] = spectrogram(data, window_size, overlap, nfft, fs);
S_dB = mag2db(abs(S));
```

Fill in the values with whatever you have.

Here's also some fast plotting for you:

```
figure;
imagesc(T, F, S_dB);
axis xy;
title('Spectrogram in dB');
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)');
colorbar;
```